# Concluding the proof of the Baire category theorem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let $(M,d)$ be a complete metric space, $A_n\subseteq M$ be nowhere dense for $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $x_0\in M$ and $r_0>0$.

> We can show that there is a $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq M$ and $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ such that $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:r_n<\frac{r_0}{2^n}\text{ and }\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\setminus\overline{A_n}\tag1.$$

In fact, since $A_1$ is nowhere dense, there is a $x_1\in B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\overline{A_1}\ne\emptyset$. And since $B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\overline{A_1}$ is open, there is a $r_1\in\left(0,\frac{r_0}2\right)$ with $$\overline B_{r_1}(x_1)\subseteq B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\overline{A_1}\tag2.$$ Continuing this procedure, we obtain $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as claimed.

Now, by construciton, $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\subseteq\overline B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\tag3$$ and hence $$\forall n\ge m\ge0:x_n\in\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq\overline B_{r_m}(x_m)\tag4.$$ Moreover, $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}=B_{r_0}(x_0)\cap\bigcap_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}^c\tag5$$ and hence $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_0}(x_0)\cap\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}^c=B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}\tag6.$$ By $(4)$, $$d(x_m,x_n)\le r_{\min(m,\:n)}\xrightarrow{m,\:n\:\to\:\infty}0\tag7$$ and hence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is Cauchy. Since $M$ is complete, there is a $x_\infty\in M$ with $$d(x_n,x_\infty)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag8.$$ By $(4)$ and $(6)$, $$x_\infty\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}\tag9.$$

> The desired conclusion is that $M\ne\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$. Or, the even stronger conclusion, that $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ is dense.
>
> However, we should even have shown that $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}$ is dense, since we have shown that for arbitrary $x_0\in M$ and arbitrary small $r_0>0$, there is a $x_\infty\in M$ with $d(x_0,x_\infty)<r_0$.
>
> From this it clearly follows that $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\supseteq M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}$ is dense as well; which in turn clearly implies that $M\ne\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$.
>
> However, my question is: If our goal is only to show the original claim (i.e. the denseness of $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ wouldn't it be sufficient to choose the radii such that $B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\setminus\overline{A_n}$ (instead of $\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\setminus\overline{A_n}$) or would the given argument fail at some point?

Comment: Replacing the density of $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$ by the density of $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}$ is not a big deal since a closure of a nowhere dense set $A_n$ is nowhere dense, so we could initially assume that each $A_n$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not true in general.

Consider $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, let $\Bbb Q=\{q_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$, and for $k\in\Bbb N$ let $A_k=\{q_k\}$; clearly each $A_k$ is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$. Let $\alpha\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, and for $k\in\Bbb N$ let $x_k=2^{-k}\alpha$. Then $x_k\notin\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}A_k=\Bbb Q$, but $\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Hm, what am I missing? My intend was to show that if $A_n\subseteq M$ is nowhere dense for $n\in\mathbb N_$, then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\ne M$. I've taken an arbitrary ball $B_0\subseteq M$ with radius $r_0>0$ and constructed $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq M$ with $x_n\in B_n\setminus\overline{A_n}\subseteq B_0\setminus_{i=0}^n\overline{A_i}$, where $B_n$ is an open ball with radius $r_n\in(0,r_0/2^n)$, for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$. The idea is that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy and hence it holds $(2)$ for some $x\in M$.

Comment: In order to conclude, I need to show that $x\not\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You need to choose the balls $B_n$ a little more carefully: in addition to everything else, make sure that $\operatorname{cl}B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=0}^{n+1}\operatorname{cl}A_i$. Then $x_k\in\operatorname{cl}B_n$ for $k\ge n$, so $x\in\bigcap_n\operatorname{cl}B_n$, which is disjoint from $\bigcup_n\operatorname{cl}A_n$.

Comment: But do my $B_n$ not already satisfy $\overline B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=0}^{n+1}\overline{A_i}$? This should hold, since $r_{n+1}<r_n$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: What you wrote in that first comment doesn’t even ensure that the balls are nested, and the balls don’t appear at all in the original question. I think that you probably should write out your whole argument in detail. In any case, the shrinking radii do not guarantee that $\operatorname{cl}B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$: what if $x_{n+1}$ is very near the boundary of $B_n$?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. I think we only need to take the closed balls if we want to obtain the stronger result that $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}$ is dense (instead of the original claim that $M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ is dense). What do you think?

Comment: We also need $\overline  B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ and not merely $B_{n+1}\subseteq B_n$ to ensure that $\cap_n B_n$ is not empty. E.g. if $M=\Bbb R$ we do not want to have $B_n=(0,2^{-n}).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If you replace "$\overline B$" with "$B$" literally everywhere in my proof in the question, wouldn't we still obtain $B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and hence $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_0}(x_0)\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}$? Moreover, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ should still be a Cauchy sequence and hence we know that $x$ as claimed exists. And $x$ needs to belong $B_{r_n}(x_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This should implicitly yield that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_{r_n}(x_n)\ne\emptyset$; since $x$ belongs to this intersection.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, it is not sufficient to omit the closure: without it you cannot ensure that the intersection is non-empty and therefore cannot ensure that the limit of the sequence is in it. In Daniel’s example, for instance, it might be that the points $x_n$ converge to $0$.

Comment: Yes, it converges to $0$, but why is that a problem? The important aspect is that $x$ is guaranteed to exist and $x\not\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{A_n}$. Doesn't this still hold?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: It is not guaranteed to do so.

Comment: Even if it is obvious to you, could you please emphasize which point of the argument given in the proof in the question breaks?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Unless you ensure that the closures of the balls are nested, it simply does not follow that the limit of the Cauchy sequence is not in $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}A_n$. In Daniel’s example, for instance, that limit could be $0$, and $0$ could be in one of the sets $A_n$. E.g., if $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals $\le 0$, we might have $A_n=\{q_n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Well, okay. I guess the crucial argument is that if, instead of $(1)$, we have $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:r_n<\frac{r_0}{2^n}\text{ and }B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})\setminus\overline{A_n}\tag{1'},$$ it still holds that $x_n\in B_{r_m}(x_m)$ for all $n\ge m\ge0$, but the limit of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ only belongs to the closure of all $B_{r_n}(x_n)$, which in turn are not guaranteed to be contained in $B_{r_0}(x_n)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{A_i}$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, that’s the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For each natural $n\le i$, $x_i\in\overline{B_n}$, so $x=\lim_{i\to \infty}  x_i\in\overline{B_n}$. Therefore $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \overline{B_n}\subset M\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

Comment: At which stage is it important that we have chosen the balls such that the closure $\overline{B_n}$ is contained in $B_{n-1}$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d At the last stage. This assures that $x_i\in\overline{B_n}$ when $i\ge n$. Moreover, since $B_{n}$ is disjoint with $A_i$ for each $1\le i<n$ and $B_{n+1}$ is disjoint with $A_n$,  $B_{n+1}$ is disjoint with $A_i$ for each $1\le i<n+1$, and so $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \overline{B_n}\subset X\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've messed up the indexing in the former version of the question. For clarity, I've written down everything more explicitly. I think that we've ended up with a stronger result (maybe it's actually equivalent; I don't know) than claimed and I still don't get why we wouldn't obtain the actual claim without considering the *closed* balls. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The idea of the proof is to provide a point $x_\infty\in M\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$. The construction provides 
$x_\infty\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\overline{B_{r_n}(x_n)}$. But in order to assure $x_\infty\not\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$ we provide $x_\infty\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0} B_{r_n}(x_n)$, and this is assured by providing $\overline B_{r_n}(x_n)\subseteq B_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1})$. If we relax the latter condition then $x_\infty$ can fail to belong to $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0} B_{r_n}(x_n)$.

Comment: For instance, when $M=\Bbb R$ and  for each $n\in\Bbb N_0$, $A_n=\varnothing$, $x_n=r_n=1/3^n $, and $x_\infty=0$.